# Solution explanation: linear map with invariant subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, contest-math, puzzle

**Problem 1.** (20 points) Let $V$ be a 10-dimensional real vector space and $U_{1}, U_{2}$ two linear subspaces
such that $U_{1} \subseteq U_{2}$, $\dim U_{1} = 3$ and $\dim U_{2} = 6$. Let $E$ be the set of all linear maps $T: V \rightarrow V$ which
have $U_{1}$ and $U_{2}$ as invariant subspaces (i.e., $T(U_{1}) \subseteq U_{1}$ and $T(U_{2}) \subseteq U_{2}$). Calculate the dimension of $E$
as a real vector space.
**Solution:** Link to the solution: https://www.imc-math.org.uk/imc1998/prob_sol1.pdf

**My struggle:** I get what they mean at the first part of the solution (so the $\textit{choose a basis}$ part). But after that part they determine in one go what the matrix of the linear map looks like and out of the matrix they conclude the dimension. My question is: Why is the matrix given in the answer logical and my follow-up question would be: why do they count the dots for the dimension of the vector space? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any linear map is represented by a matrix and in particular, invariant subspaces have a nice way to visually see them on a matrix. Note that the space of $10 \times 10$ matrices $M_{10 \times 10} \cong \mathbb{R}^{100}$ with each entry being a basis element. Since the dotted elements are free to vary, they are a basis of the subspace.

Comment: Alright, I get the second part now.  Can you maybe expand on your first sentence. What is the 'nice' way to visually see them? (if it's a big subject you can also give me a link to a websource with information on this subject)

Comment: Azif00 explains why but maybe sit down and try to note it yourself with a few examples? The matrix is sort of block triangular with respect to the basis. There's a reference in Axler somewhere that talks about matrices and invariant subspaces. The logical extreme (where each invariant subspace is $1$-dimensional) is diagonalization if you think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the matrix of $T$ relative of the basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_{10}\}$ is the matrix with entries $a_{i,j}$ that satisfy
$$T(v_j) = a_{1,j}v_1 + a_{2,j}v_2 + \cdots + a_{10,j}v_{10} \textrm{ for each $j \in \{1,\dots,10\}$.}$$
So, as $U_1$ is $T$-invariant we have that $T(v_j) \in U_1$ for $j = 1,2,3$, and then $T(v_j)$ can be written as a linear combination only of the vectors $v_1,v_2$ and $v_3$. This is why $a_{4,j} = \cdots = a_{10,j} = 0$ in this case. The same happens with $j = 4,5,6$.

Comment: I don't understand your first sentence. How is that possible in this case? If you have a 10 x 10 matrix A, with elts A_ij and the matrix v_j with elements b_1,...,b_10.If you compute A(v_j) you then get: (A_11*b_1 + .... + A_110*b_10 etc). How can you create a matrix A such that you get the constraint that you mentioned?

Comment: For each $j$ compute the vector $T(v_j)$, and since $\{v_1,\dots,v_{10}\}$ is a basis for $V$, write it as a linear combination of $v_1,\dots,v_{10}$. Then you pick the coefficients in that linear combination and put them as the $j$-th column of a matrix.